# Wildcard in query for ASP.NET GridView

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

I am using GridView in ASP.NET 2.0. I am want to show the details from 3 tables (SQL2005) in the GridView per my search crieteria (Name of Visitor,Passport Number,Name of Company). It is working, but I want to use a wildcard for searching by first letter of "Name of Visitor". I have my code in the QueryBuilder in GridView (using Configure Datasource). The query is as follows:

```
SELECT FormMaster.NameofCompany, VisitorMaster.NameofVisitor,
VisitorMaster.PassportNumber, FormMaster.FormID,  
VisitorMaster.VisitorID FROM VisitorMaster INNER JOIN VisitorDetails ON
VisitorMaster.VisitorID = VisitorDetails.VisitorID INNER JOIN FormMaster ON
VisitorDetails.FormID = FormMaster.FormID WHERE (FormMaster.FormStatusID = 1) AND
(VisitorMaster.PassportNumber = @PassportNumber ) OR
(VisitorMaster.NameofVisitor = @NameofVisitor) OR
(FormMaster.NameofCompany = @NameofCompany )
```

Comment: good god almighty, could you at least attempt to put spaces between your words?

Comment: Yeah, I copypasta'ed the question into the answer block just to reformat a lot of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is:

```
SELECT
  FormMaster.NameofCompany,
  VisitorMaster.NameofVisitor,
  VisitorMaster.PassportNumber,
  FormMaster.FormID,
  VisitorMaster.VisitorID
FROM
  VisitorMaster INNER JOIN VisitorDetails ON
    VisitorMaster.VisitorID = VisitorDetails.VisitorID
  INNER JOIN FormMaster ON VisitorDetails.FormID = FormMaster.FormID
WHERE
  (FormMaster.FormStatusID = 1) AND
  (VisitorMaster.PassportNumber = @PassportNumber ) OR
  (VisitorMaster.NameofVisitor = @NameofVisitor) OR
  (FormMaster.NameofCompany = @NameofCompany )
```

Are you sure it is working correctly? When `FormMaster.FormStatusID` doesn't equal 1 and one of the last two criteria is true, it will still return that row. `AND` has higher precedence than `OR` in TSQL.

Properly, your `WHERE` clause should be:

```
FormMaster.FormStatusID = 1 AND (
  VisitorMaster.PassportNumber = @PassportNumber OR
  VisitorMaster.NameofVisitor LIKE @NameofVisitor OR
  FormMaster.NameofCompany LIKE @NameofCompany)
```

And append a % to the @NameofVisitor and @NameofCompany parameters you pass in. Doing it the way Shawn or WebMatrix suggest will have you matching everything if you don't pass in something whereas LIKE '' only matches an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

VisitorMaster.NameofVisitor like @NameofVisitor + '%'

Answer (score 0):

try"
 NameOfVisiotr **Like** 'A%' instead